# ORDER BY DATETIME DESC

Tags: php, mysql

Summarize the Problem:

I cannot get ORDER BY DESC to work.
The column that I'm trying to order is DATETIME so I should not have to do a conversion, I don't think.

Describe what you've tried:

The NULL value is the one I want to fill in with the most recent datetime from a different table
Table Image. I am able to fill in a time, but the time is not the most recent pilot_death for this pilotID #. I am not able to do ORDER BY on the datetime.

Note: Since this is complicated enough for me, I have provided the data tables in an sql query in the mediafire link here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/owucp67djcc8djp/pilot_stats.sql/file

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa4cfbf7ed044a07440f68250dc42927).

Before:
[image: image1]

Code:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE pe_DeathAncestoryFinal 
SET pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_lastpilotdeathtime = (
SELECT DISTINCT pe_LogEvent_datetime
FROM pe_LogEvent 
WHERE  pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotid = pe_LogEvent_pilotid AND pe_LogEvent_type = 
"pilot_death"
GROUP BY pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotname
ORDER BY pe_LogEvent_datetime DESC )
WHERE pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_lastpilotdeathtime IS NULL
';
```

After: I want this date in there -> 2021-04-10 19:36:02
[image: image2]

Comment: Please consider creating a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Relevant information should be included in the question itself, instead of relying on external links which may break in the future.

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax, not correlated subquery.

Comment: *fill in with the most recent datetime from a different table* There are 2 times in this "different table", `2021-04-10 19:11:20` and `2021-04-10 19:36:02`. It seems that `2021-04-10 19:11:20` shown in desired result is not "most recent"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE pe_deathancestoryfinal 
JOIN ( SELECT pe_LogEvent_pilotid,
              MAX(pe_LogEvent_datetime) pe_LogEvent_datetime
       FROM pe_logevent 
       WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = "pilot_death"
       GROUP BY pe_LogEvent_pilotid ) x ON pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotid = pe_LogEvent_pilotid
SET pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_lastpilotdeathtime = pe_LogEvent_datetime
WHERE pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_lastpilotdeathtime IS NULL
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4866412b4d46b6ec120fbd0b70939ce

Comment: Thanks! I've never heard of multiple-table UPDATE syntax before. I'm a little shocked at this x you have going on is that a cross product? GOD THAT IS SO COOL :) . Can you tell me when you generally use correlated subquery vs. multiple-table UPDATE syntax? Thanks again!

Comment: *is that a cross product?* Each DBMS have its own syntax. Sometimes the syntax of one DBMS is applicable to another, sometimes not. *when you generally use correlated subquery vs. multiple-table UPDATE syntax?* In update the correlated subquery should be used when the percent of the rows to be updated is not above ~5%. OF course only in simple cases and with optimal indexing.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll take a note of that in the future. Thanks.